# code goes in an infinite loop

Tags: linux, shell, amazon-ec2

I have a code in shell script as follows:

```
    # Setup the command.
command=`ec2-describe-snapshots | grep pending | wc -l`

# Check if we have any pending snapshots at all.
if [ $command == "0" ]
then
        echo "No snapshots are pending."
        ec2-describe-snapshots
else
        # Wait for the snapshot to finish.
        while [ $command != "0" ]
        do
                # Communicate that we're waiting.
                echo "There are $command snapshots waiting for completion."
                sleep 5

                # Re run the command.
                command=`ec2-describe-snapshots | grep pending | wc -l`
        done

        # Snapshot has finished.
     echo -e "\n"
        echo "Snapshots are finished."
fi
```

This code sometimes work fine, sometimes it dont works fine. It goes to an infinite loop. I want to do something like this i want to check the output of `ec2-describe-snapshot` that if snaphost are in pending state. if yes it should wait until all the snapshots are completed.

The output of ec2-describe-snapshots is

```
SNAPSHOT    snap-104ef62e   vol-a8  completed   2013-12-12T05:38:28+0000    100%    109030037527    20  2013-12-12: Daily Backup for i-3ed09 (VolID:vol-aecbbcf8 InstID:i-3e2bfd09)
SNAPSHOT    snap-1c4ef622   vol-f0  pending 2013-12-12T05:38:27+0000    100%    109030037527    10  2013-12-12: Daily Backup for i-260 (VolID:vol-f66a0 InstID:i-2601)
```

Comment: Hint, perhaps use `logger` inside your script.

Comment: what is that ? I am not getting anything

Comment: Does your `echo` command show that there are a non-zero number of snapshots waiting for completion?  Or do you see `There are 0 snapshots waiting for completion` and it still loops?

Comment: no a non zero no is displayed. like `There are 1 snapshots waiting for completion.`

Comment: Well that really means there is at least one pending snapshot...

Comment: @janos: yeah. sometimes the loop works fine and sometimes it doesnot.

Comment: What's the question? Script does exactly what you should expect it to do, inf-loop if there are pending snapshots and complete if not.

Comment: If it says there is 1 snapshot, *there really is* one snapshot. So it works as expected.

Comment: when i see in the amazon console, all the snapshots are completed. But still it shows the snapshots are pending!!! how come that is possible.

Comment: That's a question for amazon. Why does their command shows different thing from their web console. It seems you just have to wait.

Comment: do you mean to say that my code is correct!! amzon is wrong!!

Comment: I think your script was correct to begin with. You just have to wait until snapshots complete, that's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program *will* loop forever if there is at least one pending snapshot. Perhaps it will be helpful to print what are those pending snapshots, by changing the script like this:

```
echo "There are $command snapshots waiting for completion."
ec2-describe-snapshots | grep pending
```

But surely that doesn't happen really infinitely. You probably just have to wait. When there are no more pending snapshots, the loop will stop. Really.

Btw here's a slightly improved version of your script. It's equivalent to yours, just the syntax is improved to remove some unnecessary stuff and replace old style writing with modern methods:

```
command=$(ec2-describe-snapshots | grep pending | wc -l)

# Check if we have any pending snapshots at all.
if [ $command = 0 ]
then
        echo "No snapshots are pending."
        ec2-describe-snapshots
else
        # Wait for the snapshot to finish.
        while [ $command != 0 ]
        do
                # Communicate that we're waiting.
                echo "There are $command snapshots waiting for completion."
                ec2-describe-snapshots | grep pending
                sleep 5

                # Re run the command.
                command=$(ec2-describe-snapshots | grep pending | wc -l)
        done

        # Snapshot has finished.
        echo
        echo "Snapshots are finished."
fi
```

Comment: see my updated code in the question. do you think it will work ?

Comment: you are giving me the exact answer which i have wrote

Comment: yeah my code is `echo "There are $command snapshots waiting for completion."
                sleep 5

                # Re run the command.
                command=`ec2-describe-snapshots | grep pending | wc -l`

Comment: now when I am running my code ( given at the top) its working fine !! what should i do

Comment: To make it clear I added a full version. You'll see there a line you didn't have. That's what I meant but you didn't read properly. And btw your script was already fine, there is no problem here, you just wait for snapshots to complete, which sometimes may take a long time, apparently.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43013/discussion-between-user3086014-and-janos)

Comment: I found this updated code interesting, +1 and thanks! Also, previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515887/how-to-use-while-loop-to-check-condition-in-linux/20516467

Comment: Hi janos: please see this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678461/how-to-parse-json-with-shell-scripting-with-linux